# Add new column with each row as previous group value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```python
data = pd.DataFrame({'start':['2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05','2020-08-06','2020-08-07','2020-08-08'],
                     'end':['2020-08-03','2020-08-03','2020-08-06','2020-08-06','2020-08-06','2020-08-07','2020-08-08','2020-08-08'],
                     'score':[74, 81, 38, 49, 79, 17, 53, 69]})
```

that I need to add a new column in which each row is the `end` date from its previous group. The desired dataframe is:

```python
         start         end    prev_end  score
0   2020-08-01  2020-08-03         NaN     74
1   2020-08-02  2020-08-03         NaN     81
2   2020-08-03  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     38
3   2020-08-04  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     49
4   2020-08-05  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     79
5   2020-08-06  2020-08-07  2020-08-06     17
6   2020-08-07  2020-08-08  2020-08-07     53
7   2020-08-08  2020-08-08  2020-08-07     69
```

so that I can mark the rows where `start` is greater than the `prev_end` date as below:

```python
         start         end    prev_end  mark  score
0   2020-08-01  2020-08-03         NaN     0     74
1   2020-08-02  2020-08-03         NaN     0     81
2   2020-08-03  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     0     38
3   2020-08-04  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     1     49
4   2020-08-05  2020-08-06  2020-08-03     1     79
5   2020-08-06  2020-08-07  2020-08-06     0     17
6   2020-08-07  2020-08-08  2020-08-07     0     53
7   2020-08-08  2020-08-08  2020-08-07     1     69
```

Is there an easy solution to do this? Or some direct way without having to create `prev_end`? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove duplciates from `end` column and create dictionary by `zip` with omitted first value by indexing and pass to [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), for `mark` column compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and convert to `0,1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
data[['start','end']] = data[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

s = data['end'].drop_duplicates()
data['prev_end'] = data['end'].map(dict(zip(s[1:], s)))

data['mark'] = data['start'].gt(data['prev_end']).view('i1')
print (data)
       start        end  score   prev_end  mark
0 2020-08-01 2020-08-03     74        NaT     0
1 2020-08-02 2020-08-03     81        NaT     0
2 2020-08-03 2020-08-06     38 2020-08-03     0
3 2020-08-04 2020-08-06     49 2020-08-03     1
4 2020-08-05 2020-08-06     79 2020-08-03     1
5 2020-08-06 2020-08-07     17 2020-08-06     0
6 2020-08-07 2020-08-08     53 2020-08-07     0
7 2020-08-08 2020-08-08     69 2020-08-07     1
```

If order of columns is important is possible use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) or change order by pass list of columns in expected order:

```
data[['start','end']] = data[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

s = data['end'].drop_duplicates()
data.insert(2, 'prev_end', data['end'].map(dict(zip(s[1:], s))))
data.insert(3, 'mark', data['start'].gt(data['prev_end']).view('i1'))

print (data)
       start        end   prev_end  mark  score
0 2020-08-01 2020-08-03        NaT     0     74
1 2020-08-02 2020-08-03        NaT     0     81
2 2020-08-03 2020-08-06 2020-08-03     0     38
3 2020-08-04 2020-08-06 2020-08-03     1     49
4 2020-08-05 2020-08-06 2020-08-03     1     79
5 2020-08-06 2020-08-07 2020-08-06     0     17
6 2020-08-07 2020-08-08 2020-08-07     0     53
7 2020-08-08 2020-08-08 2020-08-07     1     69
```

---

```
data = data[['start', 'end', 'prev_end', 'mark', 'score']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `drop_duplicates`, `shift`, `reindex`

```
data['prev_end'] = data.end.drop_duplicates().shift().reindex(data.index, method='pad')
data['mark'] = data.start.gt(data.prev_end).astype(int)

Out[39]:
       start        end  score   prev_end  mark
0 2020-08-01 2020-08-03     74        NaT     0
1 2020-08-02 2020-08-03     81        NaT     0
2 2020-08-03 2020-08-06     38 2020-08-03     0
3 2020-08-04 2020-08-06     49 2020-08-03     1
4 2020-08-05 2020-08-06     79 2020-08-03     1
5 2020-08-06 2020-08-07     17 2020-08-06     0
6 2020-08-07 2020-08-08     53 2020-08-07     0
7 2020-08-08 2020-08-08     69 2020-08-07     1
```